# Can't open multiple Finder windows from terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, bash, iterm

In iTerm running bash I run:

```
open -a 'Finder'
```

that correctly open Finder. Actually a window already existed so it just brings up that window.

With this command I want to open another window even if one already exists:

```
open -n -a 'Finder'
```

but I get this error:

```
The application /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, 
error=Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed."  
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x6000015c17a0 
{Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=162 "Unknown error: 162" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}
```

What I have done:

- I've removed the quotes around the app name
- I've re-launched Finder

Nothing changes, still the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag `-n` opens a new instance of the application: it does not open a new window. Application windows are not separate instances of the application.

I presume that it's not possible to create multiple instances of the Finder.

If you want to open a new window in the Finder, use:

`open /path/to/folder/`

This will open a new window only if the location is not already open.

The `-a` flag is for when you want to open a named file with a specified application.

The `man` page for `open` will give you more information.

If you want to control Finder with scripting, you may be better off with AppleScript, or triggering a Shortcut or Automator action from the shell.